# Python: Extracting Conditional Information from a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am using Python 3.5 to iterate over a dictionary. I am trying to check for certain conditions in the dataset below, and to return a message if the condition is either untrue or if there is no data to evaluate the condition.

```
data = {
            "Barry": {
                "Title": "CTO", 
                "YOB": 1980, 
                "Direct_Reports": ["Hannah"],
                "Awards": ["Tech Innovator", "Best CTO"],
                "Salary": 1200000
            }, 
            "Joe": {
                "Title": "Data Scientist", 
                "YOB": 1981,
                "Salary": 200000
            },
            "Bill": { 
                "Title": "Senior Software Engineer", 
                "YOB": 1993, 
                "Direct_Reports": [],
                "Awards": ["Employee of the Month"]
            }, 
            "Jose": { 
                "Job": "Full Stack Engineer", 
                "YOB": 1996, 
                "Direct_Reports": ["John", "Hannah"]
            },
        }
```

For example, I can iterate over the dictionary to print the name of the people listed:

```
for name in data.keys():
    print (name)
```

or

```
for name in data.items():
        print (name[1]['YOB'])
```

to get everyone's Year of Birth.

However, if I run

```
for name in data.items():
    print (name[1]["Salary"])
```

it gives me an error, since the data doesn't capture everyone's Salary, just as not everyone has received an award.
How could I go about doing this, or extracting salaries only for people above a certain threshold, for example, 500000?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to filter out list's items based on a condition:

`[ (k, v) for k, v in data.items() if "Salary" in v ]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to see whether "Salary" is in the dictionary or not, like:

```
if "Salary" in name[1] and name[1]["Salary"]>500000:
   print(name)
```